# RegularExpression migration to SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

I have code first entity classes, and one of the columns must have length of 20 characters and contain only Latin symbols, numbers, '_' and '-' symbols.

I write this regular expression `@"^[A-Z0-9\-\_]$"`, but when run add-migration and generating the database, in SQL Server this expression is not accepted.

```
 [DataContract(IsReference = true)]
    public partial class Vendor : IBaseEntity
    {
        [Key, DataMember, MaxLength(20), RegularExpression(@"^[A-Z0-9\-\_]{1,20}$",
                                   ErrorMessage = "")]
        public string No { get; set; }
    }
```

Can help how type or migrate this restriction in SQL Server? or if this method does not work, what is other way of doing this?

**May be solved**

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
                   
            modelBuilder.Entity<Company>(entity =>
                           entity.HasCheckConstraint("CK_SomeTable_SomeColumn", "([Display Name] NOT LIKE '%[A-Z0-9\-\_]%')"));


            base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
        }
```

Comment: Do you really want the db to do the regex check? And then do what if it's failed.. throw an exception? How about just putting the regex in the `set` and doing it c# side? (And wouldn't you rather  do this in your view models? Surely by the time the data gets to the db entity it should already be "correct"?)

Comment: SQL Server just plain and simple doesn't support this kind of regular expressions .....

Comment: Thanks for answers, but I want this restriction to be accepted, saved and used in the SQL server database, or if this method does not work, what is other way of doing this?

Answer (score 1):

`HasCheckConstraint` is the correct approach. Unfortunately, the check constraint you've created doesn't match your requirement.

Your requirement is that the column contains *only Latin symbols, numbers, '_' and '-' symbols*.

Your check constraint validates that the column contains *at least one Latin symbol, number, '_' or '-' symbol*.

To properly match your requirement, you would need to use:

```
entity.HasCheckConstraint("CK_SomeTable_SomeColumn", "([Display Name] NOT LIKE '%[^A-Z0-9\-\_]%')"));
```

This pattern looks for any character which is *not* a letter, number, `_`, or `-` symbol. The pattern is then negated - any value which matches the pattern is invalid.

[LIKE (Transact-SQL) - SQL Server | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/like-transact-sql)

Answer (score 0):

Solution in EF

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
                   
            modelBuilder.Entity<Company>(entity =>
                           entity.HasCheckConstraint("CK_SomeTable_SomeColumn", "([Display Name] NOT LIKE '%[A-Z0-9\-\_]%')"));


            base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
        }
```

Comment: That check constraint validates that your column contains *at least one* letter, number, dash, or underscore. That doesn't match your requirement, that the column contains *only* letters, numbers, dashes, or underscores.